# selenium python wait time time out exception when it used to work before

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have code that is supposed to log into etsy after a certain amount of time. This code has not had any changes and used to work perfectly on an old machine that I had. Now however when I run this on another windows 10 machine, I get a time out exception.

Code:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import datetime
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.etsy.com/shop/FidoandFifi?ref=l2-shopheader-name") #navigates to hoshiikins.com
print("Navigating to website...")
browser.find_element_by_id("sign-in").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"username-existing")))
username = browser.find_element_by_id("username-existing")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password-existing")
username.click()
username = browser.find_element_by_id("username-existing")
```

It gets to the wait.until line then it times out with this message:

```
> Navigating to website...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EstyBot.py", line 183, in <module>
    main()
  File "EstyBot.py", line 180, in main
    get_item(item)
  File "EstyBot.py", line 61, in get_item
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"username-existing")))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have tried using sleep, but then I get the error that the element is not visible.

I have tried by XPATH and tried EC as `element to be visible` to only hit the same error message as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the desired locators have changed and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.etsy.com/shop/FidoandFifi?ref=l2-shopheader-name") #navigates to hoshiikins.com
  print("Navigating to website...")
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sign-in"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.input.input-large#join_neu_email_field"))).send_keys("Taryn@Antoinette.Raines")
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input.input-large#join_neu_password_field").send_keys("Taryn_Antoinette_Raines")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: signIn]

Comment: @TarynAntoinetteRaines Glad to be able to help you !!! Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.